# parent.alert event not getting fire on pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a main jsp page in which alert functionality is modified using

```
window.alert=function(txt)
```

In other jsp pages are loaded in the same document using iframe. parent.alert is used in most of these pages to keep consistency.

This is a piece of code I am working with:

```
<div onkeypress="handlekey()">
    <button id='done' onclick="example()" >submit</button>
</div>
```

Script portion is as following:

```
<script>
    function handlekey(){
        if ((window.event) && (window.event.keyCode == 13))
        {
            // click the search button
            done.click();
        }
    }
    function example(){
        parent.alert('Done');
    }
</script>
```

Alert is not fired if I press an <kbd>enter</kbd> key but get fired when I click on the button.
Alert also gets fired when I replace `parent.alert` with alert.

Comment: it doesn't do anything. and it's also get fired if i add another alert (not parent alert)in  function example().

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    window.alert = function(){
        console.log('My alert');
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html" id="myIframe"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function handleEvent() {
        if ((window.event) && ((window.event.keyCode == 13) || window.event.type == 'click')) {
            example();
        }
    }

    function example(){
        parent.alert();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div onkeypress="handleEvent()">
        <button id='done' onclick="handleEvent()" >submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```